# Angular http client interceptors not known in lazy loaded feature module

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

We have made an interceptor in Angular. This one is exported with a forRoot() in a core module. The app module imports this core module with forRoot().

In the lazy loaded feature module the interceptor is not known.

How can we fix this problem?

The http client module is imported only once in the app module.

Comment: Did you provide your interceptor so that it is available on the module it will be used?

Comment: The interceptor should be used on all modules. It is provided with a forRoot method in the core module and only the app module imports the core module.

Comment: I didn't get what you mean by providing it using forRoot. AFAIK you should provide it as { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: InterceptorClass, multi: true }. Also, did you try providing it directly on AppModule?

Comment: I used the HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, multi: true... construction. And it is set in the CoreModule.forRoot()

Comment: I would suggest you: providing it on AppModule or importing core module also on lazy loaded modules or move the interceptor to a shared module and import it on any required modules.

Comment: You mean like a forChild method?

Comment: I mean importing the modules directly, on imports array passed to @NgModule decorator, without using either forRoot or forChild

Answer (score 0):

you have to import your coreModule in each LazyLoaded module to benefit from it's services and components

to make your services **singleton**, you import your coreModule in AppModule with .forRoot and in each lazyLoaded module without .forRoot,

so if it's  your main module:

```
    @NgModule({
     imports: [
      ...
      CoreModule.forRoot()
    ],
```

if it's a lazy loaded module

```
@NgModule({
     imports: [
      ...
      CoreModule
    ],
```